# Using jQuery plugin xdomainajax.js for cross-domain Ajax calls: only one website working

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to use this plugin to make cross-domain ajax calls: [cross-domain-ajax](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/)

I tested it straight away with the BBC website, and it works, here is the simple code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res);
        $('#container').text(res);
    }
```

However, for some reason every single other URL I try doesn't work, it just does nothing.
Can anyone help me here? The BBC is not the actual website I want to use for this, this is an example URL I want to use:

http://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/assets/img/browse/

But I tried all sorts (Google, Twitter, etc. etc.), and nothing except the BBC website pulls through.
Anyone know why this might be? Does the BBC website have something special about it that allows this kind of call, where others don't?

Thanks,
S

Comment: Here's a test fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8w9ya/

Comment: Most likely the sites it doesn't work on are preventing that kind of request from happening.

Comment: This is not working anymore?!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works here ... http://jsfiddle.net/VnvtD/1/

Comment: Thanks, works with many websites. Not unfortunately with the NASA website I was trying to pull data from - which maybe makes sense given it's a .gov site. Thanks anyway!